# Sub-Query Using "NOT IN" (Selection Not Correct)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, sql, query

I am running into a bit of an issue with a query I am performing (for a void analysis).  I have two data sets, where I am trying to determine which Retailers are not within a certain geography.  When I use "**SELECT * FROM PCA_RETAIL_AZ WHERE: Retailer  NOT IN ( Select Retailer From TEST)**" I get results, but the selection also selects some of the retailers that are located within the TEST file.

Why is that?

I am not an SQL guru.  I can run this same process in MapInfo and it will work, but MapInfo is very slow in doing so.  I've attached screen shots of my results.

The image below, the selection includes just about everything from my "Test" file; so for example it selects Dillard's, when it should not as it is a part of my TEST data set.
[image]

Comment: Although you have been a user of this site for 8 months I note that you have not yet taken its 2-minute [Tour] that is designed to introduce all users to the site.

Comment: That query should work, assuming that you have a feature class named "TEST" in the same geodatabase as PCA_Retail_AZ, and assuming that TEST has a field named Retailer. You may also want to verify that the capitalization is the same between the two datasets. If not, try: `LOWER(Retailer) NOT IN (Select LOWER(Retailer) From TEST)`

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the version of ArcGIS in use, the data source, and if RDBMS, which one.

Comment: If it is a mixture of select by attributes and location, it is not going to work

Comment: Be careful if/when working with versioned data in ArcSDE databases. In these cases you need to ensure that the data in your subquery is a versioned view - [10.1 resource](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//006z0000000q000000)…. Otherwise, your query may return incorrect results

credit to @BrentEdwards

Comment: Thank You all for the responses.  The culprit was me comparing data sets outside of the SDE,